# Error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning on sending user information trhu a landing page for an API with NODE.JS

Tags: node.js

(I'm new to coding and pretty new to NODE, so I have no idea what's the issue and how to solve it.)

My code is this:

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const firstName = req.body.fname
  const lastName = req.body.lname
  const email = req.body.email
  const listId = "***";
  const subscribingUser = {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email
  };

  async function run() {
    const response = await mailChimp.lists.addListMember(listId, {
      email_address: subscribingUser.email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        FNAME: subscribingUser.firstName,
        LNAME: subscribingUser.lastName
      }
    });


    console.log(
      `Successfully added contact as an audience member. The contact's id is ${
        response.id
      }.`
    );

  }


  run();
})
```

And i'm getting this error messsege:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using async await in your code and mailchimp is throwing an error which is not getting caught because you are not handling error.
either use .then .catch as below or add try{}catch

```
function run() {
    mailChimp.lists.addListMember(listId, {
        email_address: subscribingUser.email,
        status: "subscribed",
        merge_fields: {
            FNAME: subscribingUser.firstName,
            LNAME: subscribingUser.lastName
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(
            `Successfully added contact as an audience member. 
            The contact's id is ${response.id}.`
        );
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```